# Suppose a model $A$ is $\aleph_0$-saturated. Show every n-type over T is realized in $A$

Tags: model-theory

We define:

$A$ is $\aleph_0$-saturated if for any expanision $A_{c_1,...,c_m}$ of $A$ by finitely many constant symbols $c_1,...,c_m$, every 1-type *consistent with*  $Th(A_{c_1,...,c_m})$ is realised in $A_{c_1,...,c_m}$

> Suppose a model $A$ is $\aleph_0$-saturated. Show every n-type over T is realized in $A$

Thanks!

Comment: You can prove it by induction on $n$. The case $n=1$ follows by the $\aleph_0$-saturation of $A$. For the inductive case, given an $(n+1)$-type $\Gamma(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1})$, you can write it as the union of the $n$-type given by all formulas in $\Gamma$ using only variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ and, the rest of the formulas which are formulas using also the variable $x_{n+1}$. By induction, there is a realization $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ of the $n$-type, and by hypothesis, the new type $\Gamma(c_1,\ldots,c_{n},x_{n+1})$ is a 1-type consistent with $\operatorname{Th}(A_{c_1,\ldots,c_m})$.

Comment: @Wore Why not make it an answer?

Comment: The question body should always be self-contained.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Sure. I posted it as an answer (with some slight modifications)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove it by induction on $n$.

The case $n=1$ follows by the $\aleph_0$-saturation of A. For the inductive case, given an $(n+1)$-type $\Gamma(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1})$, you can write it as the union of the $n$-type given by all formulas in $\Gamma$ using only variables $x_1,\ldots,x_{n}$ and the rest of the formulas in $\Gamma$ (which are the formulas using also the variable $x_{n+1}$).

By induction, there is a realization $c_1,…,c_n$ in $A$ of the $n$-type, and by hypothesis, the new type $\pi(x_{n+1}):=\Gamma(c_1,\ldots,c_n,x_{n+1})$ is a $1$-type consistent with $Th(A_{c_1,\ldots,c_n})$, so there is $d\in A$ realizing $\pi$.

Notice that the tuple $(c_1,\ldots,c_n,d)$ is a realization in $A$ of the original $(n+1)$-type $\Gamma(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1})$.